# How to synchronize product status changes with order status in OpenCart?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, sql-update, e-commerce, opencart

I'm working with OpenCart and currently facing a challenge with the order and product status synchronization. I need the order status to automatically update to "Delivered" when all associated product statuses change to "Delivered". Could someone guide me on where in the MVC structure of OpenCart I can find the logic that handles the state changes of both products and the overall order? Ideally, I'm looking for the controller or model files that manage these transitions, so I can implement an observer or a similar mechanism to update the order status based on its products' statuses.

Additionally, I am attaching screenshots to provide context for the current system behavior.

I'm examining the OpenCart system and haven't pinpointed where the code governs status updates for products and orders. Specifically, I'm looking for the logic that would update an order's status to "Delivered" once all products are marked as such. Could you point me to where in OpenCart's files or systems this might be managed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.